# Java Access Modifiers - Public function/variable in protected class

Tags: java, class, access-modifiers

Good day,

if I have a class somewhat like this:

```
public class A {
        protected class B {
                public int element;
                public int get() {
                        return i;
        }
}
public class C {
        foo();
}
public class D extends A {
        foo();
}
```

1.Could foo() in class C, access element and get()? Or can only class D access them?

2. If class B was private, could C access element and get()?

Comment: First, the code doesn't compile. So it's impossible to answer.

Comment: If ever the code was compiling, why wouldn't you try it and find for yourself?

Comment: No, `C` can not access `element` or `get`. `D` can though. If `B` was private no class except `B` could access the members. Here's a good table for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only D, class B is protected, then C can't access to class B.

But, you have to instantiate B in D to call to get() and get i, because get is an instance method.

If B was private, neither C neither D can access B.